# Can't trigger hover event on other element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

Hello I am trying to write a jQuery snippet which will simulate a hover event on flipbox when a button is clicked. The main problem is that I have tried all solutions given on stackoverflow for this scenario but it just doesn't seem to work at all.

[Front of flipbox in dev console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgQFN.png)

[Front of flipbox in dev console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yjGH.png)

Below are the code I have tried on this same element

```
jQuery('.eael-elements-flip-box-container').mouseenter().mouseleave();
jQuery('.eael-elements-flip-box-container').mouseover();
jQuery('.eael-elements-flip-box-container').trigger("hover");
jQuery('.eael-elements-flip-box-container').trigger("mouseover");
jQuery('.eael-elements-flip-box-container').trigger("mouseenter");
```

Comment: Are you sure it is done with JavaScript and not CSS?

Comment: you can easily achieve this using css

Comment: How exactly? any example would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could trigger the event and have an event listener on the other element like this:

```
$("#click-btn").click(()=>{
   $(".hover-me").trigger('mouseover')
})

$(".hover-me").mouseover(()=>{
  console.log('hovered')
})
```